# RethinkDB Query: How to pluck bassed on a date range

Tags: rethinkdb

Given a table called alerts and a database called database with an array
of objects with a date attribute called History how can I pluck based
on a date range on that date attribute?

with the following query,

```
r.db("database").table("alerts").pluck("history").limit(10000)
```

I get back something like the following

```
{
    "history": [
        {
          "text": "text1" ,
          "updateTime": Thu Jun 20 2019 01:29:47 GMT+00:00 ,
         },
         {
           "text": "text2" ,
           "updateTime": Thu Jun 20 2019 01:24:59 GMT+00:00 ,
          }, 
     ]
}
{
    "history": [
        {
          "text": "text3" ,
          "updateTime": Thu Jun 20 2018 01:29:47 GMT+00:00 ,
         },
         {
           "text": "text4" ,
           "updateTime": Thu Jun 20 2018 01:24:59 GMT+00:00 ,
          }, 
     ]
}
```

how can I pluck the sub object called history and only return histories that are in a specific range on the updateTime attribute. 
 for example between jan/2/2009 to jan/3/2009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter based on a time range and use pluck on a nested object. Here are some examples about how to do that from the official documentation

```
r.table("users").filter(function (user) {
    return user("subscriptionDate").during(
        r.time(2012, 1, 1, 'Z'), r.time(2013, 1, 1, 'Z'));
}).run(conn, callback);
```

Source: https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/filter/

```
r.table('marvel').pluck({'abilities' : {'damage' : true, 'mana_cost' : true}, 'weapons' : true}).run(conn, callback)
```

Source: https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/pluck/